# Unable to find "Local" window while debugging SSIS package

Tags: ssis, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to debug my package in SSIS. I need to see the value of my variables while debugging, but the problem is that I cannot find the "Local" window. The only window I have is the breakpoint window as you can see below:

[image]

What is wrong with my Visual Studio? (I'm using Visual Studio 2013)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking in the correct menu for the Locals (Ctrl+Alt+V, L) window. The issue is that this is a context sensitive menu.

With an SSIS project open, I see a similar menus as you under Debug/Windows
[image: Package editor running]

However, if I set a breakpoint and launch the debugger, then I'll get the full suite of debugging windows available under the Debug/Windows menu

[image: Debugger running]